# Finding median in a changing array

Tags: ds.algorithms, lower-bounds, data-streams, streaming-algorithms

Consider the problem of needing to support an $n$ integers array structure with two operations:

- Set(k,v) - set the $k$'th integer to value $v$ (i.e. $A[k]=v$).
- Median() - return the median value of the array.

Suppose that the median functionality has to run in $O(1)$ time.

> **What is the complexity of the `set` operation**?

---

You may assume that the array is initialized to zeros, and you can preprocessing to initialize any data structure you want.

---

Implementing `set` in $O(\log n)$ time is straightforward. 
I'm specifically interested in showing a lower bound.

---

The special case in which the `set` function may only increase the value of an element is also of interest.

Comment: This can implement the sliding window median, which would get you the desired lower bound. http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/21736/314

Comment: @ChaoXu - thanks, this doesn't quite give me the lower bound, as the implementation of this array might not be comparison based. Also, I believe that David's answer requires to know the entire input in advance, right?

Comment: Specifically, any $\omega(1)$ lower bound, without any assumptions on the way it works, would be interesting.

Comment: Are the values v assumed to be bounded? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer - no.

Comment: In that case, there should be a straight-forward $\Omega \hspace{.02 in}(\hspace{.02 in}\log(v))$ lower bound - When the first 2 Set operations are to v with distinct ks, and the next ceil(n/2)-1 are to something larger than v, a subsequent Median operation must return v, so at least 1/2 of v's bits must have been read during at least one of the first 2 Set operations. ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer - I see your point. Then I guess we can assume we are in a model where values and keys are represented using $O(1)$ memory words (otherwise this really makes no sense).

Comment: Are the values v assumed to satisfy ​ |v| ≤ poly(n) ? ​ ​ ​ That would determine whether this is on a word RAM or a [transdichotomous machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model). ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RB: You get the lower bound "it is at least as hard as sorting", so there is a nontrivial lower bound unless you happen to have a setting in which sorting can be done in linear time.

Comment: I doubt that you can find a better bound than the one given by @JukkaSuomela, because any implementation of a min-heap that supports the min operation in time O(1) and the set operation in time f(n) would also an imply a solution to your problem where the set operation takes time f(n). This is using the undergrad implementation of a median-heap using two min-heaps. Thus, the complexity of median-heap and min-heap are the same, and IIRC Thorup has a paper that shows that the complexity of min-heap is tightly related to the complexity of sorting.